# I get a 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin' error on links to videos, when my html is uploaded to the web server

Tags: javascript, html, url, video, x-frame-options

I created a simple html page that has a few html links to YouTube and Vimeo videos, such as:

```
<a href = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZV4XDyUDTTs&t=1s' ><img src="images/dragon_of_eve.png"></a>
```

After uploading my html page to the web server, these links don't work (in both Safari and Chrome on a Macbook). The javascript console gives the error:

Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZV4XDyUDTTs&t=1s' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

When I make the page open in a new browser tab, using....

```
<a href = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZV4XDyUDTTs&t=1s' target="_blank" ><img src="images/dragon_of_eve.png"></a>
```

It works. But I don't want to open the link in a new browser tab.

I have never seen this problem before. There is no javascript on my page, I never specified that these videos should be embedded or put into frames. I assumed my links would direct the user to the specified page on YouTube or Vimeo, as usual. The links were copied straight from the URL for the video. No frames involved.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
-Jeffrey

Comment: When you view source on the live site, you're not seeing any frames? Does your host do any weird auto-frame-generating stuff?

Comment: Good idea! In fact, I did what you suggested and it looks like my host did put the whole thing into a frame (???). I have no idea why! (leftover from a startup page perhaps?) I would never have known this otherwise. I will contact the host about this. Thank you very much!

Comment: FYI - I may have found the culprit: my ISP had wrapped my html page link in some html - as a way to make my domain name point to the specified source page. They did this using frames. I just asked my host if there is another way to do domain pointing.